# How to simulate key press event in python on another program running in python

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, pynput

I am running ML model, which predicts fingure gestures.I am trying to simulate key press event in python using pynput library and I check it's working fine.But I have other program which Is a game written in python using pygame library , which opens up in a new window , but the problem is key press controls doesn't work on that, but it works when I manually press keyboard buttons.

Comment: PyGame uses SDL library (Simple DirectMedia Layer) and probably it can use direct access to system's events so it may works on lower level than pynput. When I see PyGame in Reinforcement Learning then it uses code created only for Reinforcement Learning

Comment: Is there any way to perform key press simulation at lower level.?

Comment: Is there any way to perform key press simulation at that lower level? How about ctype?

Answer (score 6):

In pygame you can add events to the event queue by doing:

```
newevent = pygame.event.Event(type, **attributes) #create the event
    pygame.event.post(newevent) #add the event to the queue
```

Where `type` is the type of the event (a numerical constant) and `**attributes` a keyarg list of attributes, also predefined constants.

All these constants are defined in the `pygame.locals` module. [pygame event docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) and [pygame key docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html) list all of them.

So if you want to simulate the press of the 'a' key for example, the code would be:

```
newevent = pygame.event.Event(pygame.locals.KEYDOWN, unicode="a", key=pygame.locals.K_a, mod=pygame.locals.KMOD_NONE) #create the event
    pygame.event.post(newevent) #add the event to the queue
```

KEYDOWN is the constant corresponding to the keydown event.
`unicode` is the unicode representation of the pressed key.
`key` is a constant associated to the pressed key.
`mod` is a constant representing a modifier (if the button is pressed while also SHIFT or CAPS_LOCK is pressed, for example).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Will it work if I simulate this in one python program , and listen this event in another program?

Comment: This, I do not know. Have a try (and let me know, I am curious too).

Comment: After running above command in pygame , should that print "a" ,if I have opened a notepad ?

Comment: Ah, I see what you want now. No, is not that simple. Pygame events must be listened by the pygame listener event. As far as I know, they are not at OS level. Achieving that would require some stdout redirect to stdin of the other program or a similar trick. I think pygame is not the right tool for this.

Comment: I am listening event using keys[pygame.K_a] ....but it doesn't seems to be working. How about ctype library

Comment: Maybe. But I do not know how to help you with that, it's better you open a new question focused on the use of the library you want to use.

Comment: I solved the problem by emulating key press event  using keyboard.press and listen the same event using keyboard.Listner() both are present in keyboard library.So I didn't use pygame functions to listen the event. Thanx everyone for ur help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by emulating key press event  using keyboard.press and listen the same event using keyboard.Listner() both are present in keyboard library.So I didn't use pygame functions to listen the event. Thanx everyone for ur help.